# Retrieve name of those who are 60 years or older, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the lastname, birthdate, and age of those who are 60 years or older. So far this is how I have done it:

```
Select *
FROM ( SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,bdate,CURDATE()) AS age
FROM 
employee
) AS d
WHERE
age>=60
```

It works, however if instead of * I put lname, bdate I will get an error. " Unknown column 'lname' in 'field list'." I cannot quite figure out how to get the lastname and birthdate and I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Column names are case sensitive, that might be your error? It says lname doesn't exist so try to verify if the column name is right?

Comment: How's 'employee'  table looks like?

Comment: I double checked. It is lname and bdate as I have typed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your derived table only contains a column named "age";  try this instead:

```
Select *
FROM employee
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,bdate,CURDATE())>= 60
```